# Error while installing FreeBSD

Tags: usb, freebsd, system-installation

I am trying to install FreeBSD 11 from USB using memstick.img file but during installation process I'm getting error about it can't find usb device and mountroot > is appearing. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check by typing `?` what rootfs candidates there are. If you don't find you USB drive, it is better to choose other ways to install FreeBSD. Typically USB drives are named `/dev/da<number>`.

For example, burn a CD or DVD image and install from that. Other option is to try other USB ports (yes, seriously). Most PCs and laptops have more than 1 USB controller and it might be more compatible.

You can also try to modify USB settings in your BIOS. Sometimes there are some compatibility/legacy settings that you can switch on or off.

Comment: I tried everything you've said except installing from CD/DVD but it's not working. I'm getting error codes for that

Comment: I added some advice about altering BIOS USB settings that you can also try. But I still think the quickest solution is to boot from a CD/DVD drive (obviously not for USB).

Comment: No, there's nothing like that in BIOS. I bought my laptop in 2010. I hope my DVD drive would work because I've not used it since long time.